# Can a predicate imply another predicate?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have studied sentential calculus(propositional logic) carefully, but not predicate logic. My questions is: can we **prove**(not just simply writing it down, I mean *to prove*) "predicate implying another predicate"? (i.e. prove $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$, without referring to any quantifiers $\forall$, $\exists$)

For example, can we formally prove something like $x>3\Rightarrow x-3>0$? In my previous experience, it can not; unless writing it in a quantified manner, such like (1) and (2) below.

(1)$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},~(x>3\Rightarrow x-3>0)$

**Proof:** Let $x$ be any real number, and suppose $x>3$, then $x-3>0$, hence $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},~(x>3\Rightarrow x-3>0)$"

---

(2)$\exists x\in\mathbb{N},~(x>3\Rightarrow x-3>0)$

**Proof:** Let $x=1$, then $1>3$ is false, hence $1>3$ implies anything, so we get $\exists x\in\mathbb{N},~(x>3\Rightarrow x-3>0)$

---

I came up with this question while I was studying analysis. I want to prove a very easy theorem in a metric space chapter.
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $E\subseteq X$, and $a\in X$.
Then $(\exists r>0,~B_r(a)\cap E=\phi)\Longleftrightarrow(\exists r>0,~B_r(a)\subseteq X-E)$.

If we are allowed to directly play with "predicates", not referring to any quantifier matters, then we can just prove that $B_r(a)\cap E=\phi\Longleftrightarrow B_r(a)\subseteq X-E$, then we put a $\exists$ symbol in the front, and we get the result. But if we cannot doing this, then we should prove it as follows:

**Proof:** Suppose $\exists r>0,~B_r(a)\cap E=\phi$, then let $x\in B_r(a)$, if $x\in E$ then $x\in B_r(a)\cap E$, thus $B_r(a)\cap E\neq\phi$, a contradiction, so $x\not\in E$. Hence $x\in X-E$. Therefore, this $B_r(a)\subseteq X-E$. So we get $\exists r>0,~B_r(a)\cap E=\phi$ implies $\exists r>0,~B_r(a)\subseteq X-E$. And the proof of the inverse implication is similar and omitted. $\square$

I think this proof is lengthy, due to concretely operate the EI/EG rules.

Comment: I might use `\varnothing` rather than `\phi` to represent the empty set.

Comment: Let me try it $\varnothing$

Comment: A "general" formula like $P(x) \to Q(x)$ would never be provable in predicate calculus alone, because it is not *valid*. A particular formula like $x > 3 \to x-3 > 0$ can be proved in the "context" of a math theory, i.e. from specific mathematical *axioms* (plus logical axioms and rules). This means that the formula (if proved) will be *true* in every model that satisfy the mathematical axioms: if $\mathbb R$ is so, then the formula will be *true* in it; if also $\mathbb C$ satisfy the math axioms, then again the formula will be *true* in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Usually, an *open* formula will be interpreted as its *universal closure* : $\forall x (x>3→x−3>0)$ and thus, if we mean the existential versione we have to specify it. Trivial example : $\forall x (x > 0)$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$  while $\exists x (x > 0)$ is *true*.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when a formula that we prove has free variables, what we are really proving is the so-called *universal closure* of that formula. If you try to prove $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, what you're really proving is $\forall x_1 \cdots \forall x_n \phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. You notice this when you try to prove "without quantifiers" that $x > 3 \implies x - 3 > 0$. You just start with the assumption, $x > 3$, and argue that we can subtract 3 from both sides without changing the inequality, and conclude $x - 3 > 0$. Hence, $x > 3 \implies x - 3 > 0$. What you've "really" proved is, indeed, $\forall x (x > 3 \implies x - 3 > 0)$.

When you give your "shorter" proof of your statement about metric spaces, what you are *really* proving is
$$
\forall r>0(B_r(a)\cap E=\emptyset\Longleftrightarrow B_r(a)\subseteq X-E),
$$
which is, strictly speaking, different from what you are asked to prove, which is
$$
(\exists r>0,~B_r(a)\cap E=\emptyset)\Longleftrightarrow(\exists r>0,~B_r(a)\subseteq X-E).
$$
In fact, what you have proved is stronger, in the sense that whenever you can prove for formulas $\phi(r),\psi(r)$ that $\forall r(\phi(r) \iff \psi(r))$, then you can also prove $\exists r\phi(r) \iff \exists r \psi(r)$ quite easily. But it does take a few more steps, which is how you get your "longer" proof.

Comment: When we proof $\phi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$, is it implicitly assuming that the discourse of $x_1$ to $x_n$ is the possible largest set that makes the $\phi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ well-defined? But in this way it seems to have some ambiguity. For example, the discourse of $x+1=0\Rightarrow x=-1$ is probably $\mathbb{C}$, but the discourse of $x>3\Rightarrow x-3>0$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I haven't been very precise in this, you're right. I think that the answer that is closest in spirit to what I wrote above is that I implicitly assumed that variables are typed, so that in the $x > 3 \implies x - 3 > 0$ example the $x$ has type $\mathbb R$, and so does the $r$ in the example of the metric spaces. Then, $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ range over whatever is appropriate in this context (namely, their own types).

Comment: Is this technique allowable in formal predicate logic(predicate calculus)? I mean are they stated as a theorem or some formula in the textbooks? Or it's just a daily convention?

Comment: Standard predicate logic is untyped, and all quantifiers range over whatever set underlies the model in which it is interpreted. There are multi-sorted or typed first order languages, in which you have multiple sets in which the variables are interpreted, according to their types. My answer however wasn't really about formal logic so much as mathematicians' every day use of quantifiers. Personally, I observe that in every day mathematics we treat variables as having types, so my answer reflects that. But really, when it comes to this question, all of this is just notation/technical details.